# Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler button doesn't work when located at specific sites

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At first, my navbar in ADMIN desktop view is like this. This works without any problems. The "**add**" button is only seen by admin, like the "**edit**" button from every product.

[image]

When in mobile version, It looks like this.

[image]

When I press the "**hamburger**" button, It looks like this.

[image]

The problem comes in other linked sites. When I press the "**hamburger**" button, It shows the sites. Now I can navigate to those sites and then **FROM** those sites navigate to other sites **EXCEPT** when I go to "**add**" and "**edit**" site. When on those sites the "**hamburger**" button **doesn't open** (doesn't work), leaving me to go back by browser arrows.

[image]

[image]

The code from my header, where navbar is located.

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
        <div class="container-xl">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Decorations</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="favorites.php">Favorites <span class="badge badge-light"><?php echo $favorite ?></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="basket.php">Basket <span class="badge badge-light"><?php echo $basket ?></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <?php if (is_admin()) { //If user is admin show edit/add/delete
                        ?>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="decorations_add.php">Add</a>
                        <?php } // End of IF
                        ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="logout.php" class="float-right btn btn-outline-primary">Log out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The code from add file:

```
<body>
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form action="decorations_insert.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h3>Add a decoration</h3>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Add picture</label>
                            <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="formGroupExampleInput">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Add title</label>
                            <input name="add_title" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Add title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Add description</label>
                            <input name="add_description" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Add description">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Add price</label>
                            <input name="add_price" type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Add price">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The code from edit file:

```
 <body>
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form action="decorations_update.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h3>Edit a decoration</h3>
                        <br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Change title</label>
                            <input name="change_title" value="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Change title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Change description</label>
                            <input name="change_description" value="<?php echo $row['description'] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Change description">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Change price</label>
                            <input name="change_price" value="<?php echo $row['price'] ?>" type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Change price">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This might be because the scripts are rendered in the first page,  but not in others. Make sure the scripts used in first page is reflected in all.

Comment: (I would remove php from the tags)

Comment: @noobprogrammer I have a php tag in "add" and "edit" site that includes the header. It is linked. <?php include_once "header.php";?>

Comment: @PierreSevrain I need the PHP there if not, everyone could add or edit the site, because it is an admin only function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project is divided in multiple files. I am using "header" and "footer" files for header and footer. With PHP, I just include them in other files, so I don't need to write the code all over again or fix everyting seperetly.

The problem was that when I made a file for admin only, **I forgot to include a script link** that made the "hamburger" button functional.

I forgot it because, It didn't matter, because anyway only I can see the admin file. That's why I forgot about the script that I included in the footer. Don't make the same mistake.

The answer is, I included the footer in the "edit" and the "add" files at the bottom, and it worked. or you could just paste the script. That would work too.